# How can i make background auto adjust after text lenght?

Tags: php, css

I want to make a warning message apear on my index if the website will be unavailable or for some other reason i need to display important information.

This is my CSS:

```
.warning-container { 
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:50%; 
    height:60px; 
    border:2px solid rgba(207,35,35, 0.5); 
    border-radius:7px; 
    background-color:rgba(255,61,61,0.3) !important; 
    padding:10px;}

.warning-icon { 
    width:60px; 
    float:left;}

.warning-h1 { 
    font-size:13px; 
    color:#c91b1b !important; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    float:left !important;}

.warning-message { 
    font-size:12px; 
    color:#e31a1a !important; 
    float:left;}
```

It will display a red background with a warning icon aswell as a title for the warning and the text.

The php is not 100% yet but this is what i got.

```
<center>
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "table");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM warning";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


//if(!empty("warning")){
//  echo"";
//}else{

echo"<div class='warning-container'>";
  echo "<img class='warning-icon' src='/warning-icon.png'>";
  echo "<div class='warning-h1'>Warning:</div>";

  echo "<div class='warning-message'>";
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo "

    Warning message goes here!

    ";
    echo"</div>";

echo"</div>";

//}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: waw, just realized i forgot to say it works but i want the background to re adjust when i input longer text or use my phone. sorrey

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. Oh..and PHP is no use here...we need the output HTML..or at least a reasonable facsimile.

Comment: I'm also not clear on what *"background to re adjust"* means...re-adjust to what?

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, i will fix all my center tags. php is used because im making a page where admins will easly be able to put up these messages without accessing the codes.

the problem is when im on my phone the text apear under the background, and same happens when the text gets too long.

Comment: Without a demo it's hard to help...but have you cleared the floats etc?

Comment: @Paulie_D everything should be cleared. not sure how i can setup a demo but heres my current website www.razor.avatarland.org